# How to create a view that automatically shows all fields as a table, even if new ones are added to the entity?

Tags: views

I need to create a table view that shows all of the user accounts on the site and their fields. The client has the ability to add new fields to the user entity but I do not want to make them go into the view to add the field as well. Is there a way to have views just output all fields? I know I can change the display as an entity and select a view mode but I need this to be in table format.

Comment: Hmm.  Good question, certainly out of the box Views doesn't appear to want to do this.  But, you might be able to fake it via fields formatted as tables by selecting just the id of the entity for the field and then changing the appropriate Views field template to load and render that entity instead of just rendering the simple id.  in theory anyway, hence this being a comment and not a full answer.

Comment: Yeah, I though of doing something this, but it's a bit ugly. I thought I would post here to see if someone has another idea/module that may help.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into exactly the same use-case. So far my intuition has been to create a fieldset to which the client can add fields, and develop a new Views plugin to add a whole fieldset to a view using every field's defaults. (The challenge here is that each field has different parameters to configure when you add them to a view.)